# How to use multiple Regular expressions in ASP.NET Web Forms Regular Expression validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to validate some control's input against multiple regular expressions how can i do this with one Regular Expression validator control.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way. You need a regular expression validator for each regex you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build a regular expression using the OR operator. Check this links for more information about it:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1213089.aspx?Multiple+Format+in+Regular+Expression+Validator
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa976858(v=vs.71).aspx

If it's not possible to adapt and build a regular expression acording to your needs, you can use a custom validator and make all the validatations for each regular expression that you could need. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx) for more information about Custom Validator.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution to your problem is to use a custom validator.check the below code.this is just to give you an idea about how to use custom validator.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />                            
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="UserName" ></asp:CustomValidator>

protected void ValidateUser(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            Regex regx = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$");
            Regex regx2 = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$");
            if (regx.IsMatch(UserName.Text) == false)
            {
                CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "error message";
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else if(regx2.IsMatch(UserName.Text) == false) 
            {
                CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "second error message";
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
          else
           {args.IsValid = true;}
       }
```